# When registering keys, which number is the Kryptonite key#?

Tags: security, lock

I've just bought a new Kryptonite lock and am about to register the keys at [www.kryptonitelock.com](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/), but which number do I enter in the Key# box? Both? The keys each have two numbers, one **L***XXXX* and one **SS***XXXXX*, and they're in a different order on the big key and little keys.

(Also, I was surprised that the "Personal Password (for security purposes)" entry field on their site is in plaintext! Not very secure, especially for a lock/security company...)

Comment: My only concern with this question is that any answer, no matter how accurate, is likely to change quickly. It would be awesome if people could provide links in their answers to the Kryptonite site.

Comment: When I was looking for answers on Google before asking here, I found several people asking this elsewhere (with no answers) back in 2009, so it seems likely that Kryptonite locks will continue to have two numbers for at least a bit longer. And the answer links to a Kryptonite page to a very handy dropdown explaining the prefixes. I'll include all the prefixes in the answer too.

Comment: Nearly two years later, this question is still relevant. I just had to check what numbers are needed because I just got a new lock (on warranty, the lock broke on the last one when it was locked outside a restaurant. After hours of faffing with oil and screw drivers, I had it angle-grinded off the next day).

Comment: My key says kryptonite and the number is 1732 can you tell me which key this goes to please thanks love Caitlin Joan Leavitt.

Comment: @Caitlin joan leavitt: Your answer has been converted to a comment, as it does not answer the question.  Please refrain form using the answer forms for conversational purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I directly contacted Kryptonite customer service for an answer to this question.

I quote directly:

"The number that you need to register is just the SS followed by 5 numbers. The L code is used at the factory and is not needed."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The website is really quite ropey: it doesn't use https either, and doesn't have key# validation. In the end I just registered it as four separate keys to cover each possibility:

1. **SS***XXXXX*
2. **L***XXXX*
3. **SS***XXXXX* **L***XXXX*
4. **L***XXXX* **SS***XXXXX*

It accepted those fine. But then I checked the page where you [order replacements](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/CustomerService/OrderKeys.aspx), and this page has a prefix dropdown containing **SS** but no **L**. The SS resolves to "KryptoLocks, Evolutions, Some Cables", which matches.

Here's all the prefixes from the Kryptonite ordering page:

- BB: New York Series
- CL: 1018 and 1218 Flex Cables
- CL-MODULUS: Modulus System
- CS: 815 Flex Cables
- DSC: Evolution 3000, NY Disc Locks
- DT: Cables
- EN: Cables
- FH: Blanks Only Available
- G: Cables
- GG: Professional Padlocks
- HDL: Harley Detechable Lock
- KRY_G: Blanks Only Available
- LD: Blanks Only Available
- LH: Blanks Only Available
- LN: Cables (Short Key) or Lighted Cables (Long Key)
- M: Cables
- NK: Evolution Series 4, Hardwire Key Cables
- PP: New York Fahgettaboudit U Lock
- SS: KryptoLoks, Evolutions, Some Cables
- XL: EVXL
- YSC: Evolution 3000, NY Disck Locks